# Como redirecionar Subdominio para pasta especifica do utilizando .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, aplicação-web, htaccess, domínio

Fiz a criação dos subdomínios utilizando *wildcard*
Gostaria de entender como posso resolver o seguinte problema com  .htaccess:

```
usuario.site.com.br -> (Aponta para pasta Usuário)
fulano.site.com.br  -> (Aponta para pasta Fulano)
bug.site.com.br     -> (Aponta para pasta Bug)
```

E quais quer outros sub-domínios que eu adicionasse o .htaccess apontaria modificando de forma dinâmica.
Caso a pasta não existisse então seria apontado para o **site.com.br**

Answer (score -1):

Consegui Galera, com esse ótimo artigo aqui: https://www.it-swarm.dev/pt/php/crie-subdominios-em-tempo-real-com-o-.htaccess-php/957812701/

http://www.webmasterworld.com/Apache/3163397.htm

usando isso no .HTACCESS

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L] 
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```